# Terraform: does ".terraform.lock.hcl" lock the version of each terraform module?

Tags: terraform, terraform-modules

I use terraform to provision a web application project, which includes RDS, Memcached, Redis, EC2, Load balancer and S3 bucket. To simplify the code, I have imported several handy terraform modules, for example:

1. [security group module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/security-group/aws/latest)
2. [RDS module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/rds/aws/latest)

After run `terraform init`, terraform has generated a file `.terraform.lock.hcl`. But this file only contains a few content. I don't believe it contains all versions of imported modules.

Here is the content.

```
# This file is maintained automatically by "terraform init".
# Manual edits may be lost in future updates.

provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws" {
  version     = "3.63.0"
  constraints = ">= 2.7.0, >= 2.42.0, >= 2.49.0, >= 3.4.0, >= 3.40.0"
  hashes = [
    "h1:lf8Qex8bhCmh8TUEAU6H4brzjy3+d4BXB6gcOYnNtNY=",
    "zh:42c6c98b294953a4e1434a331251e539f5372bf6779bd61ab5df84cac0545287",
    "zh:5493773762a470889c9a23db97582d3a82035847c8d3bd13323b4c3012abf325",
    "zh:550d22ff9fed4d817a922e7b84bd9d1f2ef8d3afa00832cf66b8cd5f0e6dc748",
    "zh:632cb5e2d9d5041875f57174236eafe5b05dbf26750c1041ab57eb08c5369fe2",
    "zh:7cfeaf5bde1b28bd010415af1f3dc494680a8374f1a26ec19db494d99938cc4e",
    "zh:99d871606b67c8aefce49007315de15736b949c09a9f8f29ad8af1e9ce383ed3",
    "zh:c4fc8539ffe90df5c7ae587fde495fac6bc0186fec2f2713a8988a619cef265f",
    "zh:d0a26493206575c99ca221d78fe64f96a8fbcebe933af92eea6b39168c1f1c1d",
    "zh:e156fdc964fdd4a7586ec15629e20d2b06295b46b4962428006e088145db07d6",
    "zh:eb04fc80f652b5c92f76822f0fec1697581543806244068506aed69e1bb9b2af",
    "zh:f5638a533cf9444f7d02b5527446cdbc3b2eab8bcc4ec4b0ca32035fe6f479d3",
  ]
}

provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/random" {
  version     = "3.1.0"
  constraints = ">= 2.2.0, >= 3.1.0"
  hashes = [
    "h1:9cCiLO/Cqr6IUvMDSApCkQItooiYNatZpEXmcu0nnng=",
    "zh:2bbb3339f0643b5daa07480ef4397bd23a79963cc364cdfbb4e86354cb7725bc",
    "zh:3cd456047805bf639fbf2c761b1848880ea703a054f76db51852008b11008626",
    "zh:4f251b0eda5bb5e3dc26ea4400dba200018213654b69b4a5f96abee815b4f5ff",
    "zh:7011332745ea061e517fe1319bd6c75054a314155cb2c1199a5b01fe1889a7e2",
    "zh:738ed82858317ccc246691c8b85995bc125ac3b4143043219bd0437adc56c992",
    "zh:7dbe52fac7bb21227acd7529b487511c91f4107db9cc4414f50d04ffc3cab427",
    "zh:a3a9251fb15f93e4cfc1789800fc2d7414bbc18944ad4c5c98f466e6477c42bc",
    "zh:a543ec1a3a8c20635cf374110bd2f87c07374cf2c50617eee2c669b3ceeeaa9f",
    "zh:d9ab41d556a48bd7059f0810cf020500635bfc696c9fc3adab5ea8915c1d886b",
    "zh:d9e13427a7d011dbd654e591b0337e6074eef8c3b9bb11b2e39eaaf257044fd7",
    "zh:f7605bd1437752114baf601bdf6931debe6dc6bfe3006eb7e9bb9080931dca8a",
  ]
}
```

When starting a Ruby on Rails project, bundler uses [`Gemfile.lock`](https://bundler.io/rationale.html) to lock the version of ruby gems. When staring a frontend project, npm uses [`package-lock.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-lock-json) to lock the version of imported libraries.

Is `.terraform.lock.hcl` used for locking the version of each terraform module?

Comment: Not answering as I don't know for sure but, from my experience, it does not. In my case, I created my own modules on a separate repository, when I update them, all pipelines get the latest version, regardless of the version they have in the lock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It reads in terraform documentation about the lock file:

> At present, the dependency lock file tracks only provider dependencies. Terraform does not remember version selections for remote modules, and so Terraform will always select the newest available module version that meets the specified version constraints. You can use an exact version constraint to ensure that Terraform will always select the same module version.

So the answer to your question will be: No. For now, it does not "lock" the version of your modules.

https://www.terraform.io/language/files/dependency-lock

Comment: there's an open issue for this: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/31301

Answer (score 0):

No, the `.terraform.lock.hcl` file does NOT contain module versions. You can however make sure that the module is used in correct version by utilizing [Version Constraints](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/version-constraints) for the module. The example code depends on module source and can look like this:

```
module "eks" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version = "~> 18.30.0"
  # [...]
```

In the code above, the module is sourced from Terraform Registry and at least 18.30.0 is used, however the latest 18.30.x will be used (because of `~>` constraint type) whenever you run `terraform get -update`.

If you are using module from git repo, however, you cannot use `version` argument, instead you need to code the tag or branch name using `ref`:

```
module "vpc" {
  source = "git::https://example.com/vpc.git?ref=v1.2.0"
}
```